# Count based on number of times a record is associated with another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

Trying to get a count on a table but not the total number of times a specific record appears, but the number of times it was associated with records in another field.

For example, in the below I want to count the number of times each elem record was associated with a unique widget record.

```
       WIDGET_ELEM_INSP
╔════════╦════════╦══════╗
║ Widget ║  Insp  ║ Elem ║
╠════════╬════════╬══════╣
║   121  ║ abc    ║  12  ║
║   121  ║ tkx    ║  12  ║
║   121  ║ cvb    ║  13  ║
║   328  ║ efl    ║  13  ║
║   328  ║ rrb    ║  12  ║
║   328  ║ plw    ║  12  ║
║   328  ║ nrs    ║  12  ║
║   328  ║ itx    ║  10  ║
║   489  ║ zmy    ║  10  ║
║   489  ║ lwv    ║  13  ║
╚════════╩════════╩══════╝
      Desired Output
╔══════╦═══════════╗
║ Elem ║   Count   ║
╠══════╬═══════════╣
║ 10   ║     2     ║          
║ 12   ║     2     ║          
║ 13   ║     3     ║          
╚══════╩═══════════╝
```

Doing the below gives me the total number of times each elem record show up.

```
SELECT ELEM, COUNT(*) AS [Total Element Instances]
FROM WIDGET_ELEM_INSP
GROUP BY ELEM
ORDER BY ELEM;
```

And this gives me a listing of each elem and widget combo I need

```
SELECT ELEM, WIDGET
FROM WIDGET_ELEM_INSP
GROUP BY ELEM, WIDGET
ORDER BY ELEM;
```

The problem is I can't get them combined to show what I want. Feel like I am overlooking the obvious and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the list you want to base your results on, distinct combos of widget and element:

```sql
SELECT ELEM, WIDGET
FROM WIDGET_ELEM_INSP
GROUP BY ELEM, WIDGET
ORDER BY ELEM;
```

Why not use that using a common table expression and count off that?  You can
just use distict:

```sql
WITH ElementWidgetCombos as (
  SELECT DISTINCT ELEM, WIDGET
  FROM WIDGET_ELEM_INSP
)
SELECT ELEM, COUNT(*) as DISTINCT_WIDGETS
FROM ElementWidgetCombos
GROUP BY ELEM
```

An even easier way would be to use the distinct clause in count to count the distict values of the other column:

```
SELECT ELEM, COUNT(DISTINCT WIDGET) AS DISTINCT_WIDGETS
FROM WIDGET_ELEM_INSP
GROUP BY ELEM
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for. I knew I was overthinking this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT ELEM, COUNT(DISTINCT WIDGET) AS Total_Element_Instances
FROM WIDGET_ELEM_INSP
GROUP BY ELEM
ORDER BY ELEM;
```